# What does "=" mean within Swagger path parameter?

Tags: swagger, openapi, grafeas

What does the "`=`" mean within the path parameter of the following OpenApi / Swagger spec?

https://github.com/grafeas/grafeas/blob/master/proto/v1beta1/swagger/grafeas.swagger.json#L18

Here is an excerpt (converted to YAML from JSON for readability):

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: grafeas.proto
  version: version not set
schemes:
  - http
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  '/v1beta1/{name=projects/*/notes/*}':
    get:
      summary: Gets the specified note.
      operationId: GetNote
      responses:
        '200':
          description: A successful response.
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/v1beta1Note'
      parameters:
        - name: name
          description: |-
            The name of the note in the form of
            `projects/[PROVIDER_ID]/notes/[NOTE_ID]`.
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
      tags:
        - GrafeasV1Beta1
```

The path is defined as `/v1beta1/{name=projects/*/notes/*}` and a parameter called `name` is defined, but when I put the whole `.json` into https://editor.swagger.io, I get errors of the form:

> Declared path parameter "name=projects/*/notes/*" needs to be defined
>   as a path parameter at either the path or operation level

Answer (score 0):

I believe this swagger spec was auto-generated and the `=TEXT` within the `{param}` blocks to be an error.  I have raised this as https://github.com/grafeas/grafeas/issues/379.